# capture click of addThis button

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-networking, addthis

I am using the addThis widget to display Facebook, Twitter, Google, Blogger, Wordpress logos on my site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=xa-1324kj34h243kjh2"></script>
```

I would like to know of a way that I can capture when someone clicks one of the buttons for Google Analytics tracking reasons. I have attempted to add an onClick to an anchor, but this does not fire - presumably because the markup is re-written by the included JavaScript.

This is my code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style"> 
    <div class="share-icons" id="share-icons">
        <span id="share-title">Share</span>
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <a class="addthis_button_email left" title="Email" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'addThis', 'email']);">&nbsp;</a>

        <a class="addthis_button_facebook left" title="Facebook">&nbsp;</a>
        <a class="addthis_button_twitter left last" title="Twitter">&nbsp;</a>

        <a class="addthis_button_google left" title="Google">
        <img src="images/google.gif" alt="G" />
        </a>
        <a class="addthis_button_blogger left" title="Blogger">&nbsp;</a>
        <a class="addthis_button_digg left last" title="Wordpress">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I am using the addthis_config to report GA activity at the moment, but I wish to report to two profiles, so I am looking for a way of capturing the click as that seems like the best way around the problem.

Comment: I tried with your code and in my case, the JavaScript method is it is indeed getting called.

Comment: Do you have it in jsFiddle by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have that div appended on the DOM to ensure you could use events. Otherwise check [liveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

I haven't used addThis widget but I would try with jQuery using class name:

```
$.('.addthis_button_email').click(function(){
    //Count it...
});
```

Or using a custom method in every button:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style"> 
    <div class="share-icons" id="share-icons">
        <span id="share-title">Share</span>
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <a class="addthis_button_email left" title="Email" onClick="notifyGA(information....)">&nbsp;</a>
```